# How to Use SSR_GetDeviceData to get finger device log in zkemkeeper class?

Tags: c#, zkteco, zkemkeeper

```
zkemkeeper.CZKEM CZ = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();
CZ.BASE64 = 1;
CZ.ReadMark = true;
CZ.Connect_Net(ipaddress, port);
if (CZ.SSR_GetDeviceData(machineNumber, out Buffer, 10 \* 1024 \* 1024, "transaction", "\*", "", ""))
{

    var lines = Buffer.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1);
    List<MachineInfo> models = new List<MachineInfo>();
    
     foreach (var item in lines)
     {
    
          var values = item.Split(',');
          var model = new MachineInfo
          {
             IndRegID = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]),
             TimeStamp = Convert.ToString(values[6]),
             DateTimeRecord = Convert.ToString(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(ToTimestamp(Convert.ToInt64(values[6]))))
    
          };
    }
    
      return models;
 }
```

How to Use SSR_GetDeviceData to get finger device log in zkemkeeper class?

try to get finger device log from new models like "inBIO260" || "ACP-260" || "BioClock I"

Please help me solve this problem because this code used to work for me, but now it does not work and does not return fingerprints

Answer (score 0):

This only works for devices that support pullsdk.

If that's the case, the I advice against using the whole `zkemkeeper` mess. Instead here is a much cleaner alternative: https://github.com/MuaazH/ZKTeco_PULLSDK_Wrapper
It uses the same native, but the API is much cleaner.

To read a fingerprint ([Read more](https://github.com/MuaazH/ZKTeco_PULLSDK_Wrapper/blob/3fd783eddecdb6daed0d960d326724cc72dfefe1/PullSDK_core/AccessPanel.cs#L118)):

```
device.GetFingerprint(userPin, finger);
```